# Couldn't resolve the value from EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE test 
   (TESTID NUMBER(3,0), 
    C1 NUMBER(3,0), 
    C2 NUMBER(3,0), 
    C3 NUMBER(3,0)
    );
Values in the table:
insert into test values(1,2,3);


declare
val VARCHAR(20);
begin
for i in 1..5 
loop
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT''C'||to_Char(i)||''' from test where tid=:1' INTO val
using i;
dbms_output.put_line('Value of Column is '||val);
end loop;
end;
```

-- Here I am seeking the value of column(i) but the output is coming as

anonymous block completed
Value of Column COL1

Instead of COL1, I am seeking 1.

Any help, advance thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Think you don't want to select `'C1'`,... but `C1`,... from the table `test`, so use:

```
declare
  val VARCHAR(20);
begin
  for i in 1..5  loop
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT C'||to_Char(i)||
                       ' FROM test WHERE tid=:1' INTO val USING i;

    dbms_output.put_line('Value of Column is '||val);
  end loop;
end;
```

`SELECT ''C'||to_Char(1)||'''...` means `SELECT 'C1'...` - it's the approach to escape `'` in ORACLE.